# Как сделать чтение и запись в одном запросе?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Добрый день. Стоит задача регистрации и надо записать данные и потов вывести данные. Надо сделать всё в 1 запросе. Как быть?

Comment: Варианты: 1. Триггер. 2. Хранимая функция. 3. Хранимая процедура. 4. Вьюшка на хранимую функцию. 5. Ещё один коннект через ADO activex. Уточните что вы хотите. Или вам все 5 вариантов отписать?

Comment: Добавьте к запросу предложение OUTPUT https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql

Comment: @nick_n_a если можно то все  5

Comment: Давайте уточним задачу. Например: Хранимка, записываем `exec  login=@login, pass=@pass`, хранимка вернет таблицу три поля  `id, login, pass`. Как то записать данные / вывести данные - не совсем однозначно.

Comment: @nick_n_a есть 2 Таблицы в одном логин пароль а в другом токены .При регистрации мы должны для этого логин пароля   заинсертить токен. а потом вывести этот же токен .

Comment: Вы уже попробовали output, он вас чем то не устраивает ? `insert into token output inserted.* values(...)`

Comment: @Mike можете показать мне его реальизацию?

Comment: Эммм. Что значит показать реализацию, это готовый запрос в него осталось только подставить имя таблицы, колонок и вставляемые значения

Comment: аа понел щас попробую

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам надо использовать `OUTPUT` в вашем запросе, осуществляющем вставку.

Выдержка из документации по SQL Server, полный текст можно прочитать по [ссылке](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms177564(v=sql.120).aspx)

> **Предложение OUTPUT (Transact-SQL):**
>
> Возвращает данные из строк, изменившихся в результате выполнения
>   инструкций INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE или MERGE, или выражения на основе
>   этих данных. Эти результаты могут быть возвращены приложению, например
>   для вывода подтверждающих сообщений, архивирования и т. п. Результаты
>   также могут быть вставлены в таблицу или табличную переменную. Кроме
>   того, можно записать результаты предложения OUTPUT во вложенных
>   инструкциях INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE или MERGE и вставить эти результаты
>   в целевую таблицу или представление.